# MySQL database connection trouble when setting up TeamCity?

Tags: mysql, teamcity

> Unexpected exception MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SQL error when doing: Taking a connection from the data source
>   SQL exception: Unknown database 'teamcitydb'

I'm getting this error when I open the Web UI for the TeamCity server in firefox, and I'm not sure why it can't take a connection to this database. I followed all the steps in the installation procedure.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked that the db exists?

Comment: the db name inside mysql is NOT the same as what you've configured the app to use, or you're connecting to the wrong mysql server. in other words, you walked into a McDonald's and ordered a Whopper, and were properly told that that's not available.

Comment: How would I go about fixing this? Should I uninstall mysql server and install it again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not create for database in the MySQL correctly.

According to the [latest manual](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Setting+up+an+External+Database#SettingupanExternalDatabase-DefaultInternalDatabase), you should run below command after connecting to the MySQL:

```
create database teamcitydb collate utf8_bin;
create user <user-name> identified by '<password>';
grant all privileges on <database-name>.* to <user-name>;
grant process on *.* to <user-name>;
```